# Temporarily overwrite page margin

Tags: javascript, css

If I have my page margin set to 5 or 10 pixels is there anyway to overwrite that for something I want to cover the entire width of the page?

If I have my page margin set to 10 and there is something I want to cover the page width and I set it to zero, it still has the 10... it uses that as the default for maximum margin

sample...

http://www.gootar.com/foobar.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use div inside body to creat margin - eg

```
<body>
  <div id="main-content" style="margin: 10px">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="div-all-over-the-page" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px">
     ...
  </div>
</body>
```

or you may want to se margin via class and overwrite it on fly from javascript

EDIT: Classic javascript on fly replacement

```
document.body.style.margin = '20px'; // for body
document.getElementById( 'foo-bar' ).style.margin = '20px'; // for specific element
```

Comment: How would you overwrite it on fly from javascript?

Comment: That changes the body on the fly but foo-bar is still whatever the body is set to.

Comment: that was just complete example - not idea to set both

Comment: Looked at your link - and js solution is not good for this - pack elements where you need margin into div or set it using class